# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError-No implementation found for native method

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native, android-ffmpeg

showing error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError-No implementation found for native method. While loading system libraries.

```
    static {
      System.loadLibrary("openh264");
    System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");
    System.loadLibrary("yuv");
    System.loadLibrary("heyhou_video");

} //and
 public native void cut(String audioPath, long starttime, long needtime, String outputPath, VideoListener listener); //here also getting error
```

Comment: Should one of the listed libraries contain the implementation of the native method? If so, check if the lib indeed contains the method and with the correct signature. If not, add the correct library.

Comment: i didn't got it

Comment: i tired many ways but still showing same problem but its demo project working fine with same libraries